# deleting multiple rows from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I got a sql table, say of the form

```
name         age
h             1
a             2
r             3
i             4
```

I want to delete the 1st row and 3rd row. 
I want something of the form,

```
delete from tablename where name=h,r;
```

is this the correct syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE name IN ('h', 'r')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
delete from tablename where name='h' or name='r';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You may use or operator or in condition like
delete from tablename where name='h' or name='r';

delete from tablename where name in ('h', 'r');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditional operator such as `OR,

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE  name = 'h' OR name ='r'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use or operator or in condition like

```
delete from tablename where name='h' or name='r';
```

Or

```
delete from tablename where name in ('h', 'r');
```